# XSLT apply two templates and to be in the same structure ( Task and Assignment fields to be in Task node)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XSLT mapping:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:wor1="http://www.example.com/services/"> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <wor1:ReceiveWorkOrderNotification> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateTaskAssignmentEx/Task" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateTaskAssignmentEx/Assignment" />
    </wor1:ReceiveWorkOrderNotification> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="Task"> 
    <Task>
    <wor1:taskId><xsl:value-of select="CallID"/></wor1:taskId>
    </Task>
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="Assignment">
  <Assignment>
  <wor1:engineer><xsl:value-of select="AssignedEngineers"/></wor1:engineer>
  </Assignment>
</xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And result is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <wor1:ReceiveWorkOrderNotification xmlns:wor1="http://www.example.com/services>
            <header>
                <wor1:taskId>test6666</wor1:taskId>
            </header>
            <Task>
                <wor1:taskId>test6666</wor1:taskId>
            </Task>
            <Assignment>
                <wor1:engineer>John Smith</wor1:engineer>
            </Assignment>
        </wor1:ReceiveWorkOrderNotification>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But I want field engineer from the Assignment to be in the Task. Can someone please resolve this since I am trying different cases but always receiving an error.
I want this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Body>
            <wor1:ReceiveWorkOrderNotification xmlns:wor1="http://www.example.com/services>
            <header>
                <wor1:taskId>test6666</wor1:taskId>
            </header>
                <Task>
                    <wor1:taskId>test6666</wor1:taskId>
                    <wor1:engineer>John Smith</wor1:engineer>
                </Task>                 

            </wor1:ReceiveWorkOrderNotification>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Never only state you get "an" error.

Comment: Hi Rad I tried within the Task node to set it like this but without success    <xsl:template match="Assignment">
    <wor1:number>
     <xsl:value-of select="AssignedEngineers"/>
    </wor1:number>
   </xsl:template>   
  </Task>

Comment: @Rad any help maybe?

Comment: Can you show the input XML you are using, please? You should also show the XSLT you are getting an "error" with, as well as the actual error message you are getting. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting an error that xls:template cannot be under the Task. Input XML is similar to the original output - Task and then its properties and the Assignment and then its properties. You can see the first result and you can see what I want in another result?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorganize your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:wor1="http://www.example.com/services/"> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <wor1:ReceiveWorkOrderNotification> 
      <Task>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateTaskAssignmentEx/Task" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="UpdateTaskAssignmentEx/Assignment" />
      </Task>
    </wor1:ReceiveWorkOrderNotification> 
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="Task"> 
    <wor1:taskId><xsl:value-of select="CallID"/></wor1:taskId>
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template match="Assignment">
    <wor1:engineer><xsl:value-of select="AssignedEngineers"/></wor1:engineer>
  </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```